# Enable Crossdomain on Safari / Firefox

Tags: firefox, safari, cross-domain

I need to enable crossdomain access on FF and Safari. I did this on Chrome (an attribute --disable-security-access) and IE (Disabling from Options->Security).

I need to disable it from browser, not other kind of solution. JSONP, Proxy, Acces-Control from server, no one is a valid solution. Just disable security from browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this option was disabled from Firefox. No news about Safari